# Unable to download file served by my custom plugin

Tags: php, export

So I'm quite new to WordPress, and WordPress development. I've created a small plugin that does one thing.

It takes in a large json string and spits it out in a nice CSV format.

The problem is when I run it inside of WordPress, even though the code executes, nothing happens.. no file is created, the browser doesn't get prompted with a file to download.

It works fine locally...I'm at a loss and I've lost a lot of hair over this..

After reading several posts I've tried numerous different ways, headers etc...

Do I need to change the .htaccess file or something? Why is WordPress stopping this file from coming into existence!

Here is the code

```
if(isset($_POST["info"])){

    $fileData = json_decode ($_POST["info"]);

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='export.csv'");
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    for($i = 0; $i < count($fileData); $i++){

        foreach ( $fileData[$i] as $line ) {
            $val = explode(",", $line);
            fputcsv($fp, $val);
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);

    echo $fp;

    error_log("Working?...");

    exit;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, we _might_ not be able to get a good answer for you on this because it might be more relevant to server setup - or PHP - than WordPress specifically.

Comment: You have no error handling, if something goes wrong your code has no checks to tell you ( what if `fopen` failed? or `$_POST['info']` is empty? )

Comment: The issue is, the code works outside of WordPress on a local WAMP server but not inside the WordPress environment (with a vanilla install). Meaning...some default WordPress setting are blocking the file from generating or...there is something I'm drastically missing here